# How can I display category in wordpress post thumbnail?

Tags: css, wordpress, html

Hello guys hope your all doing well. I was looking for some help for a slider im building on my wordpress site. I cant seem to figure out how to display the category of each post that shows in the slider and have it highlighted. Does anyone know how i can accomplish this? my current code is below

```
<div id="slides">       
    <?php if (function_exists('yg_randomposts')) {
         $parameters = array(
            'limit' => 10, //Number of posts to show
            //'excerpt' => 60,  //excerpt length (letters)
        'actcat' => true, //get posts current 
            'cusfield' => 'post-image', //custom field name of thumbnail image
            'w' => 250,  //width
            'h' => 250, //height
            'firstimage' => true,  //get first image of post content
            'atimage' => true, //get first attached image of post
            'defimage' => 'http://watchthefeed.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/random-post-default.jpg' //default thumbnail image
        );

        //print random posts
        yg_randomposts($parameters);
        } ?>
</div><!--slider container-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Would `wp_get_post_categories` help?  You can read more about it in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_categories), including usage and arguments that can be passed.

Comment: Thanks for your response..I tried this but no help :-/ any other suggestions?